# Transform PHP into PNG

Tags: php, json

I have these scripts: **http://pastebin.com/RuHKcAfc** http://pastebin.com/f3xXdigj

As you can see in the live version here: http://thegelu.com/tfm/helpers.php the json data (http://api.formice.com/helper/online.json) is printed on a php-created picture

```
$imagem = new Image(502, 500, '#1C3C41');
```

I'd like to add my own image like helpers.png, not helper.php

Comment: PHP into PNG ????????????

Comment: I don't know how to explain it. I want the data from the json file to print into an image (e.g: helpers.png), not helpers.php

Comment: This is a vague question. What you want is to render a PNG file with some text in it.

Comment: so data in Json are png data? how do you create them? which php function do you use?

Comment: If you want a real answer you will have to add more information else you will be downvoted to oblivion

Comment: if you want your image displayed as a png file you should do as arheops said, if this image will change in the future, you should redirect a request to image.png to image.php with mod_rewrite. you can find certain tutorials on the internet, like this one: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the PHP GDI Functions you can create your own images with text, already existing images and more. There is a lot of documentation online that will help you with this. Since your question is fairly vague, I will not partake in typing code.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

Answer (score 1):

1) execute script on your web server

2) press ctrl-printscreen

3) stat paint

4) ctrl-v

5) remove all except picture.

6) save as png

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which web server you are using. You will usually be able to set up an internal redirect on your server ([Apache uses mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)).